# MUI TimePicker fired on click compensates for every render?

Tags: next.js, material-ui

MUI 
TimePicker fired on click compensates for every render?
It's not even visible in Google Developer Tools.

I can't see it when I try to find it in the developer tools.

I want to CSS customize the timePicker that appears when clicked.

[image]

I want to CSS customize the timePicker that appears when clicked.

I tried to check the google developer tools but it doesn't show up.